# Is there a similar tool to `tee` for stdin?

Tags: bash, io-redirection

`tee` works by  reading from stdin and splitting the input stream to stdout and a file.

I am trying to do a similar thing with a process's stdin. I would like for a command's stdin to be still be attached to the tty, or pseudoterminal and also be able to receive input from an arbitrary source, say a file.

I have tried a variety of pipe tricks and IO redirection and can't duplicate the desired scenario of the program seeing stdin as the terminal.

This might not be possible, but I figured I would ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how a file is involved in your scenario; piped standard input can be read into a temporary file (or held in memory) and then tty access restored via something like

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect

package require Tcl 8.5
package require fileutil

set tmpfile [::fileutil::tempfile]
while {[gets stdin line] >= 0} {
    puts $tmpfh $line
}

close stdin
open /dev/tty r+

# and here the remainder of the program can interact with the terminal,
# and read from the $tmpfile as necessary
```

I use this method to [`feed` standard input into REPL](https://github.com/thrig/scripts/blob/master/misc/feed) and then turn that REPL over to interactive use:

```
$ echo '(print "hello")' | feed - sbcl --noinform
* (print "hello")

"hello"
"hello"
* (quit)
(quit)
$
```

Comment: I need to get more familiar with expect. Thanks, this got me on the way.

Comment: Thanks for this, but is there a way to capture control code responses from the tty? I would like to be able to see device status report responses with cursor position etc.

Answer (score 3):

You could write a program that calls `select()` on the tty and some other source, reading whatever comes out of either one. But if the other source is a file, that doesn't make any sense: files can always be read immediately, there's no waiting for input. So the result would be that you'd either handle the file first, then the tty input, or the other way around. (Unless the file is very large, and you need to actually wait for the disk for some measurable time.)

To read a file first, and then tty input / stdin, you could just use `cat file -`.